# Java Servlets Forwarding a view in which there is a link to a css

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet in which doGet and doPost call a processRequest method.

**processRequest method:**

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    request.setAttribute("content", this.getViewContent(request, response));
    request.getRequestDispatcher("views/layouts/default.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

**getViewContent method:**

```
protected String getViewContent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CharArrayWriterResponse content = new CharArrayWriterResponse(response);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("views/frontend/home.jsp").forward(request, content); 

        return content.getOutput();
}
```

**default.jsp:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
          href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/assets/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <%= request.getAttribute("content") %>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the style.css file returns:
**HTTP Status 500 - Cannot forward after response has been committed**

I haven't touched the web.xml.

Using apache tomcat 7+ under 64bit ubuntu.

Comment: That doesn't have to do with the CSS. It's caused by the getViewContent() method. It seems like you want to create a template engine. Why don't you use Tiles or Sitemesh?

Comment: Yeah, that is an option, but at the moment I'm trying to stay away from third-party libraries as much as possible. Isn't this doable without having to install additional libraries? It seems like something that shouldn't be a problem and it isn't in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

The error nothing to do with css. In your `processRequest()` you are calling `getViewContent(request, response)` which is forwarding the request to `home.jsp`. you cannot forward again to `default.jsp`. That's when Tomcat throws that error.

Comment: I was able to do that - It took the contents of home.jsp and rendered it inside default.jsp. My issue is that I cannot make it work with the css file.

Answer (score 0):

I've don't saying exactly, I think maybe like this, As the sample code is following as:

```
RequestDispatcher view=request.getRequestDispatcher(EMPLOYEE_LIST);
    request.setAttribute("users", dao.getAllUsers());
    view.forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of capturing the output of your view JSP and then inserting it into your template JSP, try calling the view as an include in the template:

**processRequest** stays the same.

**getViewContent** becomes:

```
protected String getViewContent(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        return "views/frontend/home.jsp"; // Note this is now returning the name of the JSP, not the JSP content
}
```

And finally, in **default.jsp**:

```
...
<body>
    <jsp:include page="${requestScope['content']}" />
</body>
....
```